# How to get WebView details information by calabash-android？

Tags: calabash, calabash-android

I plan to use calabash-android to develop automation test script for android app. 
     But i don't know how to touch/query the "Register" button in below page：
     [image]

I tried to 'query "*"' in calabash console but can not get any info about the 
button. The query output:

```
    irb(main):002:0> query "*"
[
    [0] {
                        "id" => nil,
                   "enabled" => true,
        "contentDescription" => nil,
                   "visible" => true,
                       "tag" => nil,
               "description" => "com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$De
corView{b11eeb10 V.E..... R.....I. 0,0-768,1134}",
                     "class" => "com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$De
corView",
                      "rect" => {
            "center_y" => 617,
            "center_x" => 384,
              "height" => 1134,
                   "y" => 50,
               "width" => 768,
                   "x" => 0
        }
    },
    [1] {
                        "id" => nil,
                   "enabled" => true,
        "contentDescription" => nil,
                   "visible" => true,
                       "tag" => nil,
               "description" => "android.widget.LinearLayout{b10779d0 V.E..... .
.....I. 0,0-768,1134}",
                     "class" => "android.widget.LinearLayout",
                      "rect" => {
            "center_y" => 617,
            "center_x" => 384,
              "height" => 1134,
                   "y" => 50,
               "width" => 768,
                   "x" => 0
        }
    },
    [2] {
                        "id" => "content",
                   "enabled" => true,
        "contentDescription" => nil,
                   "visible" => true,
                       "tag" => nil,
               "description" => "android.widget.FrameLayout{b1234b00 V.E..... ..
....I. 0,0-768,1134 #1020002 android:id/content}",
                     "class" => "android.widget.FrameLayout",
                      "rect" => {
            "center_y" => 617,
            "center_x" => 384,
              "height" => 1134,
                   "y" => 50,
               "width" => 768,
                   "x" => 0
        }
    },
    [3] {
                        "id" => nil,
                   "enabled" => true,
        "contentDescription" => nil,
                   "visible" => true,
                       "tag" => nil,
               "description" => "android.widget.LinearLayout{b11ecf40 V.E..... .
.....I. 0,0-768,1134}",
                     "class" => "android.widget.LinearLayout",
                      "rect" => {
            "center_y" => 617,
            "center_x" => 384,
              "height" => 1134,
                   "y" => 50,
               "width" => 768,
                   "x" => 0
        }
    },
    [4] {
                        "id" => "NoResourceEntry-6",
                   "enabled" => true,
        "contentDescription" => "Web View",
                   "visible" => true,
                       "tag" => nil,
               "description" => "org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser.InAppBrowser$6$
5{b108af68 VFEDHVC. .F....I. 0,0-768,1134 #6}",
                     "class" => "org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser.InAppBrowser$6$
5",
                      "rect" => {
            "center_y" => 617,
            "center_x" => 384,
              "height" => 1134,
                   "y" => 50,
               "width" => 768,
                   "x" => 0
        }
    }
]
```

Would you please give me some suggestions? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your app: Is native or hybrid?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer this thinking your app is an hybrid app. I'm not sure this works for native apps. I doubt it.
If you want to get some information about all your elements in DOM you should use this instruction:

```
query("systemWebview css:'*'")
```

That instruction will return an array with all elements on the web view. You'll get classes, ids, etc. If you want to get only the elements which textContent contains the word Register (which will help you find it easier) you should run this:

```
query("systemWebview css:'*' {textContent CONTAINS 'Register'}")
```

Check the results and tell me: Is that what you want?

Comment: I checked two commands in calabash-android console, but nothing return. Just empty []

Comment: Well. Firstable, are you sure it is a hybrid app? Other way your app is not going to show any webview.

Comment: How can i confirm this app type? I'm a novice at these things.

Comment: How about this return, That is not webview?      
      "id" => "NoResourceEntry-6",
                   "enabled" => true,
        "contentDescription" => "Web View",
                   "visible" => true,
                       "tag" => nil,
               "description" => "org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser.InAppBrowser$6$
5{b108af68 VFEDHVC. .F....I. 0,0-768,1134 #6}",
                     "class" => "org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser.InAppBrowser$6$
5",

Comment: To the first comment: If you did the app with tools like ionic or cordova, it's hybrid. Also you can plug your device on your PC, go to chrome://inspect, open the app on your mobile & inspect it. Check elements tab, if it has the look of a web page then its hybrid.

Comment: The second comment: I haven't look anything like that LOL. But its probably hybrid. I'm seeing cordova plugins so it must be.

Comment: It should be hybrid as the Developer said. This page was generated by SAP HANA Cloud Platform Plugin. I think the "register" hide in ""id" => "NoResourceEntry-6"". But i don't know how to find it out.

Comment: It is very rare. When you go for "systemWebview css:'*'" query it must show every single element there.